# Can't check ActiveX Toolbox after saving and reopening worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, activex

I'm creating an Excel vba-based application in which specific data should be shown, and for filtering this information I'm trying to use ActiveX Chekboxes.

After I create the checkboxes I can check/uncheck them normally, and I use some macros to perform somethings I want, for example, to make sure only one option can be checked I use:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If Worksheets("Cover").CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("O8") = 1
If Worksheets("Cover").CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("O8") = 0

If Worksheets("Cover").Range("O8") = 1 Then
 Worksheets("Cover").CheckBox2.Value = False
 Worksheets("Cover").CheckBox3.Value = False
 Worksheets("Cover").CheckBox4.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that, after I save this worksheet and reopen it to start working again, I can't check or uncheck the boxes anymore. I also can't format them on Designer Mode anymore (if I right-click one of the checkboxes and select 'Properties' a window to change the properties of the active worksheet appears). And, of course, the macros don't work anymore (Runtime error '438').

Does anyone have a clue about what may be the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!